# navigation Bar not covering screen properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to coding, so this is probably very simply to fix but i'm just not seeing it. I have two screens set up and a navigation Bar in both screens. On the first screen it fills the space but on the second it doesn't. How do i fix the problem? There is also another problem with the colours not looking the same.

Page one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHs6c.png)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customNav()
    }
}
       func customNav() {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        }
```

Page two

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSM0i.png)

```
@IBOutlet weak var bar: UINavigationBar!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            customNav()
        }
    }

    func customNav() {
        bar.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        bar.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
        bar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    }
```

Comment: try to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` or put `customNav()` inside `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: @ZonilyJame that didn't work, any other suggestions ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add screenshots of your view heirarchy?

Comment: sorry, i can not embed images because i'm not level 10, but i can link. i have linked them in the post

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I lost my internet connection yesterday. You should embed your `viewController` inside a `UINavigationController for the `navigationBar` to appear